# Get Azure Active Directory token from an electron app

Tags: electron, azure-active-directory, adal

What would be the best way to obtain an AAD token from an electron app?

Microsoft has 2 javascript authentication libraries: `adal.js` and `msal.js`.
Both are designed for browsers and not native `Electron` apps (For example - AAD won't allow for `file:///` scheme as a reply URL).

Sounds like a long term solution would be native AAD packages (like Microsoft built for [Apache Cordova](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-cordova-multitarget/)), but since that's probably not going to happen any time soon, what is the best short-term option?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/)  is a good example of an Electron app that does this. It even allows for being logged into multiple AAD accounts at the same time.

You might be able to check out what's going on in the app's dev tools. I've had a poke around and it looks like it uses [adal-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node) npm package instead of the browser based js libraries.

It also looks like it uses an authorization code flow for obtaining tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @paul-lucas!  I am looking through the Azure Storage Explorer source code:  https://github.com/Azure/deco. and for the life of me I can not figure out how this is authenticating with AAD.  Any idea where this is handled? 
For adal-node, won't it expose the client secret when this is packaged in an electron app?

Comment: @jfbloom22, good question, I'm not sure about the secret with adal-node tbh. I think that deco repo is actually the code for the original storage explorer. I believe it has changed significantly since then, and the new storage explorer isn't open source. Sorry, I don't know much more than that.

Comment: ah ok, yeah it would make a whole lot of sense if the old explorer, the repo I am searching, does not even have AAD auth.  Too bad they did not open source the new one.  FYI I am going the direction of a Cordova deploy to Windows since there is a Cordova ADAL plugin that supports windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD doesn't support the file protocol as the reply address. To develop the single page application, you can host it on the server and using the server URL as the reply address.